# Go Dependency Error in SAM application when building with AWS Toolkit

Tags: go, aws-lambda, dependencies, aws-sam

I have a SAM application that has several endpoints (with their own module) and a seperate module in the same project that has helper functions, services etc.

When building the project with `sam build`, which should build and deploy all endpoints at once, it causes an error in the build process. The dependencies are definitely included in all related go.mod/go.sum files.
Here's the error:

```
Running GoModulesBuilder:Build

Build Failed
Error: GoModulesBuilder:Build - Builder Failed: ..\..\service\matchService.go:10:2: missing go.sum entry for module providing package github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws (imported by testmodule/service); to add:
        go get testmodule/service@v1.0.0
..\..\service\matchService.go:11:2: missing go.sum entry for module providing package github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session (imported by testmodule/service); to add:        go get testmodule/service@v1.0.0
```

If I execute `sam build` in the endpoint folder directly it works flawless however!

This is the basic folder structure of the project:

```
/api/matches/endpoint-a/main.go
/api/matches/endpoint-a/go.mod <- requires matchService of "testmodule" which lies in /, also requires aws-sdk-go indirectly
/api/matches/endpoint-a/go.sum
/services/matchService
/go.mod <- requires github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws
/go.sum
/template.yaml <- includest AWS::Serverless::Function for endpoint-a
```